# Trouble using 'helper_method' and rendering templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, controller

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to set an `helper_method` that should work just for a controller (example: AccountsController) and for all views related to that, also when its views are rendered in another views not related to that controller. I take inspiration from the [Railcast "Restricting Access"](http://media.railscasts.com/videos/020_restricting_access.mov).

In my accounts_controller.rb file I have

```
# Just to know, I am using a User namespace...
class Users::AccountsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :show_authorization

  def show_authorization
    false # This returning value is just an example
  end
end
```

In my views/users/accounts/show.html.erb file I have

```
<% if show_authorization %>
  You are authorized!
<% else %>
  You are NOT authorized!
<% end %>
```

The above code works if I browse the URL `http://<my_app_name>/users/accounts/1` but if I render the `show.html.erb` file as a template in another view file this way:

```
<%= render :template => "/users/accounts/show", :locals => { :account => @account } %>
```

I get the error:

```
NameError in Users#show 
undefined local variable or method `show_authorization' for #<#<Class:...>
```

**Why? How can I solve that in order to make the AccountsController `show_authorization` method available to the `show.html.erb` view when that is rendered in another view related to another controller?**

*P.S.*: Since the `show_authorization` is related only to the AccountsController and its views file, I would like to don't insert the related code in the 'application_controller.rb' file but keep that in the 'accounts_controller.rb'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The helper_method is practically almost the same as a defining method in accounts_helper.rb (technically it eval code against helper class). In order to use this helper you need to define it in a helper module and include it in controllers where show template meant to be rendered.

The actual problem is that different controller would know nothing about your accounts controller helpers until you explicitly require to include them.

Examples:

```
module Users::AccountsHelper
  code_here
end

class ApplicationHelper
  helper Users::AccountsHelper
end
```

all account helper methods will be available across application