# How to include explicitly a controller method in its helper file so it is possible to include that helper in another controller and use that method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to include a controller (accounts_controller.rb) method explicitly in its related helper file (accounts_helper.rb) so that I can include that helper in another controller and use its methods. I need that because I can move out in helper the method code stated in accounts_controller.rb, but I need to use that method in others controllers.

Since this question is also related to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390125/trouble-using-helper-method-and-rendering-templates), I thinked to solve the latter this way:

(1) in accounts_controller.rb I state

```
def method_name
  ...
end
```

(2) in accounts_helper.rb I can include the `method_name`... *how to do this?*

(3) in posts_account.rb I can include accounts_helper.rb... *how to do this?*

**Is it a good approach? If so, how can I code the steps 2 and 3?**

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the method across controllers and views/helpers you can declare it as a `helper_method`

In your `application_controller`

```
helper_method :some_method

def some_method
  // some common stuff
end
```

This will make the method available across controllers and views

Comment: if you don't want to move method to application_controller.rb. Then use the #helper_method in accounts_controller.rb and use inheritance for other controllers.
class PostsController < AccountsController;end

Comment: whoa did not realize how old this question was. @Will edited the question and it popped up on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

One idea --  put the helper method in application_controller.rb then you can declare when to expose it to the view in a per controller basis - or globally in the application_controller.rb.

Comment: As I wrote in the question (and also in the linked question), "I can not"\"I would like not" move the methods "out from accounts_controller.rb"\"in application_controller.rb".

Answer (score -1):

If you need to use the method in multiple controllers then I'd suggest it's reasonable to put it in `application_controller.rb`

Comment: As I wrote in the question (and also in the linked question), "I can not"\"I would like not" move the methods "out from accounts_controller.rb"\"in application_controller.rb".

Comment: It actually says "I can move" if we're being picky. Why exactly can't you move it out of there?

Comment: Sorry, maybe the phrase is ambiguous. However I can't move it out because the method is related mainly to the controller and not to the helper (that is - as people say, if I move that method out, I "break" the MVC architecture), but I need that method also in other controller.